# Time zone independent

Tags: java, jaxb, timezone

I have a class that convert DateTime as below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateFormatConverter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

  private static final String XML_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z";

  @Override
  public Date unmarshal(String xmlDate) throws Exception {
    if (xmlDate == null || xmlDate.length() == 0) 
    {
      return null;
    }    
    SimpleDateFormat xmlDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(XML_DATE_PATTERN);    
    return xmlDateFormat.parse(xmlDate);
  }

  @Override
  public String marshal(Date date) throws Exception {
    if (date == null) {
      return "";
    }    
    SimpleDateFormat xmlDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(XML_DATE_PATTERN);    
    return xmlDateFormat.format(date);
  }
}
```

And my unit test:

```
public void testMarshalDate() throws Exception {

    DateFormatConverter converter = new DateFormatConverter();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormater  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date date = dateFormater.parse("10-13-2011");

    String marshalledDate = converter.marshal(date);

    String timezone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT);

    System.out.println("Default Timezone:" + TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
    System.out.println("Timezone of formatter:" + dateFormater.getTimeZone().getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
    System.out.println("Timezone:" + timezone);
    System.out.println("MarshaledDate: " + marshalledDate);

    assertEquals("Marshalled date string is not expected.", "2011-10-13 00:00:00.000 " + timezone, marshalledDate);
  }
```

The output in console is:

```
Default Timezone:ICST
Timezone of formatter:ICST
Timezone:ICST
MarshaledDate: 2011-10-13 00:00:00.000 ICT
```

Exception is:

```
Marshalled date string is not expected. expected:<...S...> but was:<......>
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Marshalled date string is not expected. expected:<...S...> but was:<......>
```

Why the marshaled date has timezone ICT while the default timezone of my location is ICST. How should I fix to make the Timezone independent?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're seeing the difference between "part of a time zone" and "the time zone name". For example, the zone in the UK uses GMT and BST, both are *really* part of a time zone with an ID of "Europe/London" although I don't know what the display name would be in that case.

If you don't *need* the default time zone here, specify it as something like UTC in the formatted when you create it. (Call `setTimeZone` after the constructor call.)

Comment: I fixed it, the problem is the cause of this line:

Comment: I fixed it, the problem is the cause of this line:     String timezone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT); Let change true to false, because by default SimpledateFormat use non-daylight format (in this case is ICT).